# Laravel 4.2 Mail::queue not sending mail (SuperClosure exception)

Tags: php, laravel, email, queue

The system can send mail (from Laravel) but `php artisan` (which uses php cli) causes errors and doesn't send mail.

For clarity I'm using the `sync` database driver.

From `php artisan tinker`:

```
> Mail::queue('emails.test', [], function($message) { $message->to({email})->subject('Test'); });
```

Errors:

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/{user}/{project}/releases/20190425
154529/vendor/d11wtq/boris/lib/Boris/EvalWorker.php(152) : eval()'d code): failed to open stream: No such
 file or directory in /home/{user}/{project}/releases/20190425154529/ven
dor/jeremeamia/SuperClosure/src/Jeremeamia/SuperClosure/ClosureParser.php on line 190                    

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'The closure was not found within the abstract syntax tree.' in /home/{user}/{project}/releases/2019
0425154529/vendor/jeremeamia/SuperClosure/src/Jeremeamia/SuperClosure/ClosureParser.php:119              

Stack trace:                                                                                             
#0 /home/{user}/{project}/releases/20190425154529/vendor/jeremeamia/SuperClosure/src/Jeremeamia/SuperClosure/ClosureParser.php(172): Jeremeamia\SuperClosure\ClosureParser->getClosureAbstractSyntaxTree()                                                                                
#1 /home/{user}/{project}/releases/20190425154529/vendor/jeremeamia/SuperClosure/src/Jeremeamia/SuperClosure/SerializableClosure.php(108): Jeremeamia\SuperClosure\ClosureParser->getCode()                                                                                               
#2 /home/{user}/{project}/releases/20190425154529/vendor/jeremeamia/SuperClosure/src/Jeremeamia/SuperClosure/SerializableClosure.php(75): Jeremeamia\SuperClosure\SerializableClosure->createState()                                                                                      
#3 [internal function]: Jeremeamia\Super in /home/{user}/{project}/releases/20190425154529/vendor/jeremeamia/SuperClosure/src/Jeremeamia/SuperClosure/ClosureParser.php on line 119
```

I've obfuscated my paths with `{obfuscation}` throughout (to be clear).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/jeremeamia/super_closure/issues/83 might help

Comment: Not using Zend Guard, but thanks for the look anyways.

Comment: I'd suggest that you're running different versions of PHP on web vs CLI, or your code requires something from web like a Request object, or you have some debug code that only runs in tinker. I'd also suggest that whatever this library code is that uses `eval`, you consider carefully whether you want to be using it.

Comment: I'm using the same version of PHP (5.6) for both instances.